# Gui: need to serialize a sequence of BackgroundWorker calls

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF app in which I've implemented some BackgroundWorker threads to update the Gui. Sometimes it works perfectly, other times I get variable out of range exceptions (when the same code is targeted by several threads simultaneously).

What is the simplest way to ensure I use ONE BackgroundWorker at a time to avoid these code clashes. In other words I want to make the BackgroundWorker calls sequential instead of paralell. I still want my GUI to be responsive. And the BackgroundWorker processes are fast enough that sequential speeds are adequate. I've attempted 'lock' and 'semaphore' but they don't seem to work with the BackgroundWorker constructs. Any quick fixes?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Sure you could fix this with a ThreadPool with a single thread. But it probably would not. Issue is, you would still have two different threads running at one time (background and the UI). Consider switching to a single threaded async programming model, or, learn how to actually write multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

A global lock will prevent worker threads running concurrently. Having said that its not an approach I would choose. I'd rather use the Task Parallel Library for concurrent computations and Async for asynchronous IO. Here we go:

```
    static object glock = new object();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (BackgroundWorker w1 = new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            w1.DoWork += (s, we) => 
            {
                lock (glock)
                {
                    //Some computation 
                    we.Result = 1;
                }
            };
            w1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        using (BackgroundWorker w2 = new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            w2.DoWork += (s, we) =>
            {
                lock (glock)
                {
                    //Some computation  
                    we.Result = 2;
                }
            };
            w2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I discovered tasks and taskfactorys with continuations. That's a much more flexible solution for my current project than the background worker. 
I'm using the synchronous option for continuations and its giving me the results I need.

Thanks for the help

Comment: NOOOOOO Don't use continuations. They are extremely buggy. Use async/await instead.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on the bugginess of continuations and the merits of async/await